# snscrape: snscrape.base:Errors: blocked (404), blocked (404), blocked (404), blocked (404)

Tags: python, twitter, scrape

I used the below code for scrapping twitter english textual posts before 5 days. and the code were working fine and i successfuly scraped data but now i am getting error. I also upgrated the sncrape library. After upgrading libraries i am getting the same error.

code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
scrapping_link = "https://twitter.com/tim_cook"
mycnt = 10
csv_file = "E:/django project/mywebsite/static/multiple posts/scraped_tweets.csv"   
username = scrapping_link.split('/')[-1]  # Extract the username from the URL   
count = 0  # Counter for the number of scraped tweets
tweets_data = []  # List to store the tweets    
for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterUserScraper(username).get_items():
  if count >= int(mycnt):
    break   
  if tweet.lang == "en" and tweet.content:
    tweet_text = tweet.content
    tweets_data.append({"username": username, "text": tweet_text})
    count += 1
# Create a pandas DataFrame from the tweets data
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_data, columns=["username", "text"])
# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv(index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

error is:

```
ERROR:snscrape.base:Error retrieving https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/7jT5GT59P8IFjgxwqnEdQw/SearchTimeline?variables=%7B%22rawQuery%22%3A%22from%3Atim_cook%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22product%22%3A%22Latest%22%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%7D&features=%7B%22rweb_lists_timeline_redesign_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22blue_business_profile_image_shape_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22verified_phone_label_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22vibe_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22view_counts_everywhere_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22longform_notetweets_consumption_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_awards_web_tipping_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22freedom_of_speech_not_reach_fetch_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22standardized_nudges_misinfo%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22interactive_text_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_text_conversations_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_rich_text_read_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_inline_media_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_enhance_cards_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_twitter_blue_verified_badge_is_enabled%22%3Atrue%7D: blocked (404)
CRITICAL:snscrape.base:4 requests to https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/7jT5GT59P8IFjgxwqnEdQw/SearchTimeline?variables=%7B%22rawQuery%22%3A%22from%3Atim_cook%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22product%22%3A%22Latest%22%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%7D&features=%7B%22rweb_lists_timeline_redesign_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22blue_business_profile_image_shape_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22verified_phone_label_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22vibe_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22view_counts_everywhere_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22longform_notetweets_consumption_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_awards_web_tipping_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22freedom_of_speech_not_reach_fetch_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22standardized_nudges_misinfo%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22interactive_text_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_text_conversations_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_rich_text_read_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_inline_media_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_enhance_cards_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_twitter_blue_verified_badge_is_enabled%22%3Atrue%7D failed, giving up.
CRITICAL:snscrape.base:Errors: blocked (404), blocked (404), blocked (404), blocked (404)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ScraperException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a22aa37f9c43> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 count = 0  # Counter for the number of scraped tweets
      8 tweets_data = []  # List to store the tweets
----> 9 for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterUserScraper(username).get_items():
     10   if count >= int(mycnt):
     11     break

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/snscrape/base.py in _request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, timeout, responseOkCallback, allowRedirects, proxies)
    269                         _logger.fatal(msg)
    270                         _logger.fatal(f'Errors: {", ".join(errors)}')
--> 271                         raise ScraperException(msg)
    272                 raise RuntimeError('Reached unreachable code')
    273 

ScraperException: 4 requests to https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/7jT5GT59P8IFjgxwqnEdQw/SearchTimeline?variables=%7B%22rawQuery%22%3A%22from%3Atim_cook%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22product%22%3A%22Latest%22%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%7D&features=%7B%22rweb_lists_timeline_redesign_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22blue_business_profile_image_shape_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22verified_phone_label_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22vibe_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22view_counts_everywhere_api_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22longform_notetweets_consumption_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_awards_web_tipping_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22freedom_of_speech_not_reach_fetch_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22standardized_nudges_misinfo%22%3Atrue%2C%22tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22interactive_text_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22responsive_web_text_conversations_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22longform_notetweets_rich_text_read_enabled%22%3Afalse%2...
```

i am trying to scrape twitter english language posts with sncrape libraray. Can anyone know how to solve this problem? Keep in mind i do not want to scrape data with API.

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue.
https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/996

Currently, scraping tweets without login seems impossible.

Comment: can you provide more information regarding to scrapping through login? Does you mean it by using API?

Comment: Yes, using Twitter API or scrapping with login/authentication work.